# thymeleaf syntax for authorize function

Tags: html, spring, web, thymeleaf, web-frontend

I want to use sec:authorize for specific division but i can not find the proper syntax

i am using the next

```
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('theAuthority')"
```

The Authority should change automatically and it is created by three parts where the middle is the dynamic.
So example of authority is :

1. part1 is static : text1|
2. part2 is dynamic: ${object}
3. part3 is static: |text3

So i have tried:

```
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('text1|${object}|text3')"
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('text1|'+${object}+'|text3')"
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('text1|'& ${object} & '|text3')"
```

What is the proper syntax

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''text1|'+object.code+'|text2'')')}"